# R Studio is running very slow after upgrade to R 4.0.3

Tags: r

I have just updated R and Rstudio, because with previous versions RStudio started working slowly 2 days ago.
Now upgraded R and Rstudio, however sometimes even commands like 1+1 takes more than 5 min to run.

Do you know the possible solutions to this problem? Packages are located in local directory.

Comment: Even after a complete restart of your computer?

Comment: Yes. Now trying to install devtools. And it is showing this line already for last 25min.   '   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/testthat_2.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1974250 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/devtools_2.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 339003 bytes (331 KB)
downloaded 331 KB   '

Comment: What OS are you using?